# setTimeout function didn't work in if else condition - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have code like this:

```
var saveToDB;
if ($('.new_article')[0]) {
  saveToDB = function() {
    var form;
    form = $('.new_article');
    $.ajax({
      url: '/admin/articles',
      type: 'POST',
      data: form.serialize(),
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        $('.form-status-holder').html('Saving...');
      },
      success: function(data) {
        var jqObj;
        jqObj = jQuery(data);
        $('.form-status-holder').delay(5000).hide();
      }
    });
  };
  $('form input, form textarea').on('input propertychange change', function() {
    var timeoutId;
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    return timeoutId = setTimeout((function() {
      saveToDB();
    }), 5000);
  });
  return;
} else if ($('.edit_article')[0]) {
  saveToDB = function() {
    var form, id;
    form = $('.edit_article');
    id = (form.attr('action')).split("/").pop(-1);
    $.ajax({
      url: '/admin/articles/' + id,
      type: 'POST',
      data: form.serialize(),
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        $('.form-status-holder').html('Saving...');
      },
      success: function(data) {
        var jqObj;
        jqObj = jQuery(data);
        $('.form-status-holder').delay(5000).hide();
      }
    });
  };
  $('form input, form textarea').on('input propertychange change', function() {
    var timeoutId;
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    return timeoutId = setTimeout((function() {
      saveToDB();
    }), 5000);
  });
  return;
}
```

I got problem with `setTimeout` function in `if` condition while it cannot call to `saveToDB` inside. It takes me hours to find where is the problem come from but now I still get stuck. The second `setTimeout` function in `else` condition works correctly. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you try to set  var timeoutId; globally instead of declaring inside functions. bcz its value always override to new variable.

Comment: Mistake in comment... removed